# Android Fragments Not Being replaced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to fragments and running into some trouble with my navigation bar fragments. I have set up the navigation bar fine, when I select a item from the navigation the layout is inflated fine but the old layout doesnt disappear and is left sitting either ontop or underneath then new layout.

The new layout should have the toolbar and navigation drawer fragment but not the tabs and their layout.

Can anyone explain where I have goen wrong?

**Main Activity Creating Tabbed layout & Nav itemSelected**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_list,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_shopping,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_add,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_search
    };

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new PossibleRecipes(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new ShoppingList(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new AddRecipe(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFrag(new SearchRecipes(), "FOUR");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //fragment = new HomeFragment();
            //title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            //break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FavouritesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_favourites);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new HelpFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_help);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

**Main Activty.XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.rory.pocketchef.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**One of the Navigation drawer XMLs (HELP.XML)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.HomeFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:text="HOME"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Edit fragment_home.xml to change the appearance" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OnDrawerItemSelected` you set `fragment = new FavouritesFragment();` or `fragment = new HelpFragment();`. So below that you should probably do;

```
if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment); //Here was the error. container is a FrameLayout
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

Note that this line `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout, new FavouritesFragment());` was edited.

Also, note that `container_body` has a height of `0dp` and `layout_weight` doesn't work in `FrameLayout` which the `CoordinatorLayout` extends... The `ViewPager` is set to `fill_parent` as well.

I don't understand the purpose of `container_body` in your UI... What is it supposed to do? Where should it appear?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I was just trying that to see if it would work that way, the code was originally like the way you suggested

Comment: @JJSmith, the `ViewPager` fills the whole parent so the `container_body` has no space...was this a mistake or by design?

Comment: @JJSmith, I don't see how the `container_body`, in which the `Fragment`s are inflated will be seen by the user. Maybe that's the error? See my edit above

Comment: I just forgot about the container_body, i wasnt sure of its purpose completely, so should the main activity layout be placed inside the container_body and then that is what is replaced by the new fragment layout?

Comment: Is your aim to replace the whole `ViewPager` with other `Fragment`s when selected from the Drawer?

Comment: So that the user sees the `ViewPager` with `Tab`s, or `FavouritesFragment` or `HelpFragment`? Kinda like the playstore screens so to speak?

Comment: That is correct yes, but when I try `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment);` the screen just goes blank and nothing is displayed, Yes like the playstore

Comment: In my view, you should just create new `Activity` for the Fragments you inflate into `container_body` and get rid of the `Fragment`s. Since a `ViewPager` contains `Fragment`s it would not be pragmatic to place it in a `Fragment` as you will be nesting `Fragment`s

Comment: You can't do `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment);`, you can only replace a `FrameLayout`

Comment: What would you suggest i do then?

Comment: As I said above, add `Activities` in place of the `Fragment`s. So you'd have `FavouritesActivity` and `HelpActivity`, so you'll be starting activities in `OnDrawerItemSelected`